# Is glVertexAttribPointer Invalidated When Switching Buffer Objects Or Shaders?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

If I make a call to `glBindBuffer`, followed by `glVertexAttribPointer`, followed by another `glBindBuffer` with different buffer but same attribute format, do I need to re-call `glVertexAttribPointer`, or is `glVertexAttribPointer` a global setting that persists despite buffer changes?

Do I need to call `glVertexAttribPointer` when switching shaders (if I know the attribute locations are the same between shaders) or is it a global setting that persists despite shader changes.  I'm fairly certain that it is the latter in this case since I typically call `glVertexAttribPointer` before any shaders are compiled.

Note, I don't have access to VAO's (this is in OpenGL ES 2.0, without the VAO extension).

Answer (score 0):

You are making assumptions that may work with the particular OpenGL ES driver you are using now, but I would not expect it to work across a range of devices with different GPUs and drivers because you are going against the spirit of the Khronos specifications and common practice.  I doubt there would even be any performance gained because these calls are not the bottlenecks.  Generally, you should do all the glVertexAttribPointer() calls after glUseProgram() and glBindBuffer() and immediately before glDrawArrays().  Changing the glBindBuffer() late is probably less risky than changing shaders late, but it is already challenging enough writing portable code, particularly for Android where there are so many different OpenGL ES implementations.